# Led Blinking with PIC16F877A

Tags: pic

I'm trying to make a 7 segment using PIC16F877A. 
I'm programming my PIC with a replica PICKIT 3.

I'm uploading my hex code using PICKIT 3 software and MPLABX IDE. 
I have no problem while I'm uploading my code but when i set up my circuit.

I noticed only B1 pin is working. I did a blink led circuit and I still get B1 pin high when I set D0 pin to high. I'm using 4 MHz crystal and 0.1 uF capacitors. I uploaded hex files from internet too but I am always getting high from B1.
­

Comment: Prolly better asked @ https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Show your code that configures, sets, and clears the B register.

Comment: Problem not explained properly, do you want to interface 7 segment display with microcontroller  or you want to blink led, provide more details like, code and diagram.